# Capture user when creating COM+ object with CreateObject

Tags: .net, windows, security, com

I have a COM+ application that exposes a .net dll.  It is running under a defined account.  The .net component logs calls made to the com app, and so captures this account as the current user using **System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name**.

The COM+ app is hosted on server A, but will be called from servers B,C, and D.

The backend db requirements are that operations be performed per-user, so it is insufficient from the db security perspective to execute methods under the account the COM+ is running under - we need to know the specific user.

We have the app configured to run using a defined account on the Identity tab, and on the Security tab are using Packet/Impersonate.

Hence my problem:  The COM+ app runs as Mr. White on Server A.  Mr. Pink executes a script on Server B that calls CreateObject("Com+App", "Server A").  I wish for .net to capture "Mr. Pink", but it is only ever capturing "Mr. White".

Can I capture "Mr Pink" in this scenario, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

A user in another forum helped me find a solution on SO: 
[How can I reliably check client identity whilst making DCOM calls to a C# .NET 3.5 Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674637/how-can-i-reliably-check-client-identity-whilst-making-dcom-calls-to-a-c-sharp)